# Named common block in a shared library

Tags: windows, fortran, shared-libraries, linker-errors, fortran-common-block

I am encountering a problem when I include a Fortran
subroutine in a shared library. This subroutine has a
named common block.

I have a Fortran main program that uses this common block
and links with the shared library.

The behavior is that variables in the common block set in
either the subroutine or main program are not shared between
the two.

I am using gfortran 4.9.3 under MinGW on windows. Here are the pieces of
my very simple example.

Main program:

```
  program mainp
  common/whgc/ivar
  ivar = 23
  call sharedf
  end
```

Subroutine:

```
  subroutine sharedf
  common/whgc/ivar
  print *, 'ivar=', ivar
  end
```

Makefile:

```
FC = gfortran
FFLAGS=-g

all: shltest.dll mainp.exe

shltest.dll: sharedf.o
    $(FC) -shared -o  shltest.dll sharedf.o

mainp.exe: mainp.o shltest.dll
    $(FC) -o mainp.exe mainp.o shltest.dll

clean:
    rm *.o mainp.exe shltest.dll
```

When `mainp.exe` is run, it produces `ivar = 0` instead of the correct `ivar=23`
Here are the results of some experimentation I did with `nm`.

```
nm -g mainp.o shows:
...
 00000004 C _whgc_
 nm on sharedf.o shows the same.
 nm -g shltest.dll shows:
 ...
 71446410 B _whgc_
 nm -g mainp.exe shows:
 ...
 00406430 B _whgc_
```

This is the only `_whgc_` symbol in mainp.exe.

However, when I run `mainp.exe` in gdb and set break points in both
`mainp` and `sharedf`, I can print the address of `ivar` at each break point. The addresses
are not the same.

From the behavior it seems clear that GNU ld is not correctly
 matching the `_whgc_` symbols but I'm unclear about what options
 to pass either in the shared library build or the final link to
 make it do so?

(Please don't suggest alternatives to common blocks. In my real
 application I am dealing with legacy code that uses common blocks.)

EDIT:

I tried my example on Linux/x86 and there the behavior is correct.
Of course on Linux the shared library and executable are ELF format
objects and on Windows/MinGW the format is PE/COFF.

Comment: Yes, I tried that but get this warning message: f951.exe: warning: -fPIC ignored for target (all code is position independent). I'm using a 32-bit compiler on an Intel x86 chipset. And, as expected from the warning, the runtime behavior is the same.

Comment: On Windows you may need to export/import common blocks explicitly as described [here](https://software.intel.com/en-us/forums/intel-visual-fortran-compiler-for-windows/topic/347785).

Comment: I took a look at the link you pointed me to but don't understand why it is relevant to my particular problem. I am using gfortran and from my nm experiments it appears that the common block *is* being exported. Can you be more specific?

Comment: The link basically says that you need to explicitly mark common blocks as dllimport/export for them to be accessible across dynamic library boundaries on Windows. Here's [gfortran man](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gfortran/GNU-Fortran-Compiler-Directives.html) which says the same.